# Angular - styling scroll bar inside a mat-list in a child component

Tags: angular, angular-material, scrollbar

I can't target the scroll bar in this child component, where I have a `mat-list` and 2 sections with defined height and `overflow-y:auto`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chtqjk-vdwwnd

in the css file, at the bottom you have all my tries to target the 2 scroll bars, can't find the right selectors!

Can someone enlighten me? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following appear to work:

```
#visibilityContainer ::ng-deep ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
}

#visibilityContainer ::ng-deep ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26) !important;
}
```

Please note that the `::webkit-scrollbar-track` selector must be separate from the `#visibilityContainer` selector, as the scroll bar is not actually on that element.

**[Here is a fork of the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chtqjk-yp8ntd?file=app/form-field-appearance-example.css)**

**EDIT:**
You'll need to make sure you style the `thumb` as well, like so:

```
#visibilityContainer ::ng-deep ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: blue; 
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, so this changes the style of the scrollbar correctly, but there is an issue, the scroll bar is always full length and it won't "move" as you scroll down, it stays fixed in place, any reason why?

Comment: @AJ989 It's because there's no styling on the thumb, i.e. the bit that moves. I've updated the stackblitz and the answer. Give that a go

Comment: lol..my bad, I failed the copy past in the stackblitz and copied for every rule the scrollbar-track, leaving out the thumb....adjusted it now and it works perfectly, thank you very much!! Didn't know you had to use ng-deep if not targeting a dynamic component made with angular material!

Comment: @AJ989 Having just revisited this answer, I've realised you don't! You can remove the `::ng-deep`, and it will still work.

Comment: ah, perfect, so that means that my solution wasn't working only because I didn't leave one white space between the selector and the ::-webkit part, at least I know that now, thank you!